# no suitable constructor found for JsonObjectRequest error when using volley

Tags: android, android-volley

the server returns the following JSON -

> [
>       {
>           "user_id": 1,
>           "first_name": "alex",
>           "last_name": "goft",
>           "password": "doom00",
>           "email": "alex@mail.com",
>           "username": "alexgoft"
>       }
>   ]

I am trying to retrieve it using volley the with the following function -

```
public void makeRequest() {
        final String HOST = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/";
        final String url = HOST + "get_data?type=user&username=alexgoft";
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        Toast.makeText(context, url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // prepare the Request
        JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "In succ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        try {
                            returned_json = response.getJSONObject(0);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "In error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        error.getStackTrace();
                        Log.d("error", error.toString());
                    }
                });

        queue.add(getRequest);
    }
```

The problem is that i get the following error -

```
Error:(46, 40) error: no suitable constructor found for JsonObjectRequest(int,String,<anonymous Listener<JSONArray>>,<anonymous ErrorListener>)
constructor JsonObjectRequest.JsonObjectRequest(int,String,Listener<JSONObject>,ErrorListener) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous Listener<JSONArray>> cannot be converted to Listener<JSONObject>)
constructor JsonObjectRequest.JsonObjectRequest(String,JSONObject,Listener<JSONObject>,ErrorListener) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to String)
```

What do i need to do so that `returned_json` will contain the returned json from the host?

This is how it looked in ide -

[image]

Comment: wait if have compile time errors then how come the response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass null in case you don't have any data to pass along with your request

Note : Since your response is a `JSONArray` so you need to implement `JsonArrayRequest` instead of `JsonObjectRequest` as also pointed by `@Krupa Kakkad`

```
new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
//                                            ^^^^
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
```

[`From Docs`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/1b4858087f25a8033c5136a96b750752b87e128c/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonObjectRequest.java)

```
@param jsonRequest A {@link JSONObject} to post with the request. Null is allowed and
     *   indicates no parameters will be posted along with request.
```

Constructor signature

> public JsonObjectRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject
>   jsonRequest,
>               Listener listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {

or

> public JsonObjectRequest(String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
>   Listener listener,
>               ErrorListener errorListener) {

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `JsonArrayRequest` instead of `JsonObjectRequest`.

For your reference: https://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/